# IE7-js: reapply fixes after DOM changes

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, ie7.js

I've been using [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for a while and now I need to re-apply the IE fixes after DOM changes (eg. new elements added).

How should I do so? I tried with the [`ie7-recalc.js`](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/source/browse/trunk/lib/src/ie7-recalc.js) script, but witouth success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=111) (the star) and wait for its resolution.